# DFS Recursion of a Tree, need assistance with visited issue

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I'm having issues when trying to navigate a tree that contains cycles.  My code enters an infinite loop and core dumps.  My problem is that my code isnt setting the nodes to visited after actually visiting them so it just loops forever.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include "GraphCode.h"
//#define EBUG

/******************************************************************************
static const string TAG = "GraphCode: ";

/******************************************************************************
 * Constructor
**/
GraphCode::GraphCode()
{
}

/******************************************************************************
 * Destructor
**/
GraphCode::~GraphCode()
{
}

/******************************************************************************
 * Accessors and Mutators
**/

/******************************************************************************
 * General functions.
**/

/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'createGraph'.
 * We read data from the input stream and create a graph.
 *
 * Parameter:
**/
void GraphCode::createGraph(Scanner& inStream)
{
  int nodeCount = -10;
  double connectivity = -3.5;

  MyRandom myRandom;
#ifdef EBUG
#endif
  cout << TAG << "enter createGraph\n"; 

  if (inStream.hasNext())
  {
    nodeCount = inStream.nextInt();
    connectivity = inStream.nextDouble();
    cout << TAG << "Create a graph of " << nodeCount
                << " nodes and " << connectivity << " percent connections"
                << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << TAG << "NO DATA\n"; 
  }

  // first we create the vector of empty nodes
  for (int fromNum = 0; fromNum < nodeCount; ++fromNum)
  {
    Node node = Node(fromNum);
    this->theGraph.push_back(node);
  }

  // now we have a vector so we know we can subscript
  for (int fromNum = 0; fromNum < nodeCount; ++fromNum)
  {
    Node node = this->theGraph.at(fromNum);
    for (int toNum = 0; toNum < nodeCount; ++toNum)
    {
      if (fromNum == toNum) continue;
      double r = myRandom.randomUniformDouble(0.0, 1.0);
      if (r <= connectivity)
      {
        node.addChildSub(toNum);
      }
    }
    this->theGraph[fromNum] = node;
  }

#ifdef EBUG
#endif
  cout << TAG << "leave createGraph " << nodeCount << " " << connectivity << endl; 
} // void GraphCode::createGraph(Scanner& inStream)

/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'descendFrom'.
**/
void GraphCode::descendFrom(ofstream& outStream, string blanks, Node& parentNode)
{
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << blanks << TAG << "enter descendFrom\n" << this->toStringPath(blanks) << endl;
#endif

  vector<int> listOfChildren = parentNode.getChildSubs();
  vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
  if (parentNode.hasBeenVisited() == false) 
  {
    path.push_back(Utils::Format(parentNode.getNodeNumber()));
    parentNode.setVisited(true);
    if (listOfChildren.empty())
    {
      outStream << "Path""\n" << toStringPath(blanks) << endl;
      path.pop_back();
    }

    else
    {
      for (iter = listOfChildren.begin(); iter != listOfChildren.end(); iter++)
      {
        Node& n = theGraph.at(*iter);
        descendFrom(outStream, blanks, n);
      }
     path.pop_back();
    }
  }
 #ifdef EBUG
  cout << blanks << TAG << "leave descendFrom\n"; 
#endif

} // GraphCode::descendFrom()

/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'doSearch'.
**/
void GraphCode::doSearch(ofstream& outStream)
{
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "enter doSearch\n"; 
#endif

Node& node = theGraph.at(0);
string blanks = "     ";
descendFrom(outStream, blanks, node);


#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "leave doSearch\n"; 
#endif

} // void GraphCode::doSearch()

/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'readGraph'.
**/
void GraphCode::readGraph(Scanner& inStream)
{
  ScanLine scanLine;

#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "enter readGraph\n"; 
#endif

  int firstNode, lastNode;
  firstNode = inStream.nextInt();
  lastNode = inStream.nextInt();
  assert ( 0 == firstNode);
  for(int i = 0; i <= lastNode; ++i)
  {
    Node node = Node(i);
    this->theGraph.push_back(node);
  }

  while (inStream.hasNext())
  {
    string theLine = inStream.nextLine();

    scanLine.openString(theLine);
    int parentNodeNum = scanLine.nextInt();
    Node node = this->theGraph.at(parentNodeNum);
    while( scanLine.hasNext())
    {
      int theChild = scanLine.nextInt();

      node.addChildSub(theChild);
    }
    this->theGraph.at(parentNodeNum) = node;
  }

#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "leave readGraph " << endl;
#endif
} // void GraphCode::readGraph(Scanner& inStream)

/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'toString'.
**/
string GraphCode::toString()
{
  Node node;
  string s = "     ";
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "enter toString\n"; 
#endif
  vector<Node>::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter = theGraph.begin(); iter != theGraph.end(); iter++)
  {
    node = *iter;
    s += "Node:  (" + node.toString() + ")" + "\n";
  }
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "leave toString\n"; 
#endif
  return s;
} // string GraphCode::toString()

/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'toStringChildren'.
**/
string GraphCode::toStringChildren(string blanks, const vector<int>& children)
{
  string s = "";
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "enter toStringChildren\n"; 
#endif
  Node node;
  vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter = children.begin(); iter != children.end(); ++iter)
  { 
    s += Utils::Format((*iter), 6);
  }
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "leave toStringChildren\n"; 
#endif
  return s;
} // string GraphCode::toStringChildren()

/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'toStringPath'.
**/
string GraphCode::toStringPath(string blanks)
{
  string s = "     ";
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "enter toStringPath\n"; 
#endif
  Node node;
  for (int index = 0; index < this->path.size(); ++index)
  {
    s += this->path.at(index) + "\n" + blanks;
  } 
  s += "LEAF\n";
#ifdef EBUG
  cout << TAG << "leave toStringPath\n"; 
#endif
  return s;
} // string GraphCode::toStringPath()
```

//expected output:

```
//PATH TO LEAF 
                           // PATH (   0:  T    1   2   6   9 XXX)
                            //From (   1:  T  XXX)
                           // LEAF

//PATH TO LEAF 
                              //PATH (   0:  T    1   2   6   9 XXX)
                              //From (   2:  T    3   4   5 XXX)
                              //From (   3:  T  XXX)
                              //LEAF

//my output:  
//Path
   //  0
   //  1
   //  LEAF

//Path
    // 0
    // 2
    // 3
    // LEAF
```

I have mine printing out the path correctly but I can't get the 'T' (basically calling parentNode.toString()) and the children to print on the same line as the path

Comment: If it has cycles, it isn't a "tree".

Comment: yea, but when he runs our program he is going to run the program on a "tree" that contains cycles and should print the respectable paths of the nodes that do not have any "children" which basically means they dont point to another node.

Comment: There also should be a mechanism to clean up after setting all those visited flags (once you correct the bug you asked about, which I answered).  If you are only truncating cycles, rather than multiple paths to the same node, a clean answer is to have the flag mean "being visited" rather than "has been visited" so you clear it on exit from the code that set it.  If you want to truncate multiple paths (as well as cycles) I think you need a separate pass to invert the visited flag (or a top level member to invert its meaning).

Comment: i corrected that error, thank you.  However my code still doesn't print the path when cycles are involved.  Is there anything else I cant do with the code I've given? I don't believe we can create new methods.

Comment: You wrote `if (parentNode.hasBeenVisited == false)`  Since that is an accessor function, not data member, you want `if (parentNode.hasBeenVisited() == false)`

Comment: GOT IT, thank you. now one last issue, im trying to get my code to format like so... I will post an update

Comment: sorry for the jumbled mess, i just would like it printing the parentNode, followed by a 'T' marking its been visited, and then its respectable children all on the same line.  Im finding that to be difficult when messing solely with my outStream

Comment: 1) I'm still seeing the original code.  If you still need help, I think you should edit the original post to contain the corrected (so far) code.  2) Give a sample of what output you got and what output you wanted.

Comment: i made the update, i only added the graphcode class because i'm pretty sure the rest is correct at this point in time

Comment: It appears that you wrote toStringChildren, but didn't call it.  You want the extra text before the \n in toStringPath, but did not put anything there.  Of course you also don't have the vector of children extracted where you need it, but that should be easy to fix.

Comment: so I have it now printing out perfectly except i cant get it to print "PATH" for the parentNode.  is there a simple if state i'm missing? to possibly check the graph for index 0? i'll keep working at it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Node::setVisited(bool what)
{
  what = visited; 
}
```

That assignment is backwards.  You meant

```
visited = what;
```